# htmlspecialchars in php not decoding

Tags: php, html

I have a application where I store sting as it is but while dispying, I want special characters to be converted to their HTML name like for `<` will be  `&lt`. To achieve it, I am using php inbuilt function htmlspecialchars.

Output of text with this function is achieved with following code

```
$reviewTxt = htmlspecialchars($reviewTxt);
echo $reviewTxt;
```

Now, for reviewTxt to be 'I loved you <3', it should produce `I loved you &lt;3` but should display the original text. In my case, it displays the encoded data `I loved you &lt;3`. I also tried to paste `I loved you &lt;3` instead of above php code just to see if I can get original text and yes, it shows 'I loved you <3'.

I am not sure what I am missing,

Comment: The conversion from `&lt;` to `>`should be done by your web browser.  Are you using your web browser to view the output of your php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are encoding twice with `htmlspecialchars()` / `htmlentities()`.

That causes the `&` symbol of the first result to be encoded in the second result, giving you a string like `I loved you &amp;lt;3`.

So it will show the encoded `&` followed by the litteral string `lt;`.